# c# nunit integration testing with exceptions

Tags: c#, async-await, nunit, integration-testing

I have a test I created which looks like this:

```
[Test]
public async Task MemberCannotCreateConfirmedUser()
{
    var services = UserContext.GivenServices();
    await services.LoginAsync(new Claim("User", "Member"));
    Assert.That(await services.WhenCreateUserAsync("AAAB", "AAAB", "AAAB", "FIN", emailConfirmed: true), Throws.TypeOf<ArgumentException>());
}
```

And the code that actually throws the error looks like this:

```
var principal = _httpContext.User as ClaimsPrincipal;
var isAdmin = principal?.FindFirst("Administrator") != null;
if (!isAdmin)
{
    if (model.EmailConfirmed) throw new ArgumentException("Only an administrator can confirm a new user");
}
```

When I run the test, it fails and states:

> System.ArgumentException : Only an administrator can confirm a new user

But surely that is what I am testing for. It should pass because it throws an `ArgumentException` error?

Comment: Why not just use `Assert.Throws`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I was just doing to assert incorrectly. Because the delegate is asynchronous, I need to do an async check. So replacing my Assert with this:

```
Assert.ThrowsAsync<ArgumentException>(async () => await services.WhenCreateUserAsync("AAAB", "AAAB", "AAAB", "FIN", emailConfirmed: true));
```

Fixed the issue